# sql 'str_to_date' function error truncated incorrect date value and doesn't show the right time format

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-insert, load-data-infile

I have a sql script like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'XXXXXX/sample.csv'
INTO TABLE test_01
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS (id, @DATE_01, @DATE_02, VALUE, @DATE_03)
SET `DATE_01` = STR_TO_DATE(@DATE_01, '%d/%m/%Y'), 
`DATE_02` = STR_TO_DATE(@DATE_02, '%d/%m/%Y'),
`DATE_03` = STR_TO_DATE(@DATE_03, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

The csv file looks like this:

[image]

If I check the format the three dates columns, they are 'dd/mm/yyy hh:mm'

[image]

The total rows of my file is 2000+, but I can only get 1100+ rows, the others show me error

```
1107 row(s) affected, 64 warning(s): 1292 Truncated incorrect date value: '01/12/2010 00:00' 1292 Truncated incorrect date value: '03/02/2011 00:00' 1292 ...........
Records: 2365  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 1258  Warnings: 7095
```

The dates format in the newly created table looks like this: `yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00`
[image]

Why the time are all converted to '00:00:00', how can I fix this issue? I'm new to SQL, I've been wrestling with this issue for a whole day now, please help....

This is the expected datetime format: [image]

Comment: I have removed [tag:sql-server] as this is clearly MySQL, due to the use of backticks (`\``) for delimit identifiers, that `STR_TO_DATE` is not a function in T-SQL, and other syntaxes that don't exist in the dialect. Please ensure you only tag the RDBMS you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format specifier that you are giving to `STR_TO_DATE()` only includes the date part, not the time portion. You would need to expand it, like so:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'XXXXXX/sample.csv'
INTO TABLE test_01
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS (id, @DATE_01, @DATE_02, VALUE, @DATE_03)
SET 
    `DATE_01` = STR_TO_DATE(@DATE_01, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), -- here
    `DATE_02` = STR_TO_DATE(@DATE_02, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'), -- same here
    `DATE_03` = STR_TO_DATE(@DATE_03, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')  -- and here
```

Comment: Hi this will only get hh:mm, but I also want it to show seconds in 'DATE_03', I just had a try, I couldn't get all the rows, only 1300+ rows. I'm not sure why there's no seconds in the csv file, but the data of this file is obtained by querying in a database, if I view it in MySQL, it has the correct format, but the seconds will be missing once I exported to a csv file.

Comment: @Cecilia: your input string has no seconds, so the format given to `str_to_date()` has none either - so MySQL generates a `datetime` value with `00` as seconds. The export problem is another issue, that is not related - you might want to ask a ew question for it, providing proper sample data and desired results.